# constructor delegates to itself in g++ & clang++

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, language-lawyer, delegating-constructor

Consider following program. I accidentally made a mistake in it.

```
struct T {
    int s;
    T() : T() {
        s=9;
    }
};
int main() {
    T t;
}
```

The above code compiles & runs fine in some versions of g++ like g++ 4.8.1 (See live demo [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/ROkKdTDJ3xUUPBhw) ) & clang++ 3.6.0 (see live demo [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/oEza0NM8EC90C4GY) ) & in MSVC++ 2015 but crashes at runtime. It gives me **segmentation fault** error. I think it is due to recursion I mean recursively call the constructor. But most recent versions of g++ & clang++ fails to compile this code by giving following error:

g++ 4.9.2 gives following error (See live demo [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/xoKqjuUdZRunkwWS) )

```
prog.cc: In constructor 'T::T()':
prog.cc:3:10: error: constructor delegates to itself
  T() : T() {
```

clang++ gives following error (See live demo [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ce1d74059f654f51) )

```
main.cpp:4:8: error: constructor for 'T' creates a delegation cycle [-Wdelegating-ctor-cycles]
        T() : T() {
              ^
1 error generated.
```

So, the question here is which compiler is right here according to standard ? Is it bug in one of these compilers ? What exactly is happening here in above program? Correct me If I am wrong somewhere in my understanding. Why same program exhibits different behaviour in different versions of these compilers ?

Comment: _"Why same program exhibits different behaviour in different versions of these compilers ?"_ Because the newer compilers are better the older ones. Telling you your code is broken is better than crashing at runtime.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From C++11, [class.base.init]¶6:

> If a constructor delegates to itself directly or indirectly, the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic is required.

All compilers are right – the code is broken, and the compiler isn't required to tell you so. At this point you have UB; from [intro.compliance]¶2:

> If a program contains a violation of a rule for which no diagnostic is required, this International Standard places no requirement on implementations with respect to that program.

Comment: I think behaviour should be undefined in case of ill formed NDR not implementation defined !!!